# Can we assign a integer to a object?

Tags: c++

I just wanted to know can we assign a integer value to a object directly. Here I just want to assign a rational value(22/7) to object `x`;

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class rational {
    private:
        int num = 22, den = 7;
    public:
        void assign(rational x) {
            x = num / den;
        }
};

int main() {
    rational x;
    x.assign(x);
    return 0;
}
```

However doing so gives an error of

> no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: rational = int

Comment: `22/7` is `3`. Using the raw `int` somehow defeats the purpose of your `rational` class. You rather want a constructor that takes two `int`s as parameter

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying. What would `num` and `den` be when you do, let's say `rational x; x = 5;`? It seems like `assign` should just copy both values?

Comment: I just want to assign the value 22/7 to my object x

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam Actually, you can, it's called [Converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: You can create a constructor like `rational(int x)`, then `x = num / den;` will be interpreted as `x = rational(num / den);`

Comment: @The-coder So you want to do `x = 3`? I get the impression that you are expecting the assignment `x = 22/7` to magically put `num=22` and `den=7`, but maybe I don't understand you correctly, can you show a little example of what you expect to happen? :)

Comment: what if I should do it compulsorily with a class?

Comment: @churill what I exactly want is :x should be assigned as num/den or 22/7

Comment: @churill Is  object x= num/den a valid assignment?This is what i want to know

Comment: in your `assign` method, `x` is passed by value. So, `x=num/den;` just assigns the local copy. You should pass `x` by reference. Or better write an assignment operator as suggested in @Jasper Kent's solution.

Comment: no it is not a valid assignment, the compiler is right. There is no `operator=` for `rational` and `int`, you can however write such an operator, but it is not clear what it should do

Comment: Then I should pass my object (x) as a reference for my above code to run correctly?

Comment: what is "correct" ? What should be the state of the `rational` `x` after you assigned an integer?

Comment: @The-coder No, the compiler doesn't do any magic. `x = 22 / 7` will calculate `22 / 7`, which is 3, then assign `3` to `x` by calling the appropriate converting constructor or assignment operator if available.

Comment: what I can understand is for example assigning `5`, then I would expect that `num == 5`  and `den == 1`. But I dont know what you expect from assigning `22/7`. Doing the same as in the `5` example it would result in `num == 3` and `den == 1`, is that what you want?

Comment: Please go some steps back and do an experiment. Print the value of `22/7` on the screen, eg via `std::cout << 22/7;` then you can turn back to your `rational` and decide what should happen. Currently this question seems to be based on a misunderstanding about integer arithmetics

Comment: or maybe its a completely different misunderstanding. Actually `22` and `7` are the default initializers of the members, hence to make the `rational` represent `22/7` you don't have to do anything extra, no need to assign something

Comment: another possibility is that its just a typo and you want `this->num = x.num; this->den = x.den;` but then still the code in `main` makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a converting constructor and an assignment operator:

```
class rational
{
public:
  rational (int val)
  {
     // initialize as you want
  }

  rational& operator= (int val)
  {
     // Assign as you want
     return *this
  }
}
```

But it's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. There are other problems:

1. Your class contains a pair of `int`s, not a single `int`
2. `x.assign(x)` looks like an attempt to assign `x` into itself
3. `assign` will have no lasting effect on its parameter, since it's not passed by value

Comment: i only want x to be assigned as 22/7

Comment: Is  object x= num/den a valid assignment?This is what i want to know

Comment: `assign` is a member and is probably meant to assign its parameter to `this` not modify the parameter.

Comment: No need to write `operator=` at all if you're ok with potential performance hit: executing the conversion constructor first and copying temporary `rational` afterwards.

Comment: @The-coder. What do you mean by 'i only want x to be assigned as 22/7'? Do you want `x.num` to be 22 and `x.den` to be 7?

Comment: @yeputons No need to do a lot of things if you're okay with a potential performance hit.